# Cannot set encoding, cannot display Japanese character strings

Tags: r, localization

I'm running R 4.0.2 on Linux. My main locale is set to en_US.utf8, but I have occasion to use Japanese sometimes. In this case, I need to use some character strings as column names. (These strings will eventually become the x-axis tick labels in a `ggplot()`.) I typed in the Japanese in emacs; nothing was read from a file. Here is the code:

```
house.names <- c("name", "平屋", "マンション", "湯河原 マンション", "熱海 マンション")
```

However, if I look at the character vector, none of the Japanese displays:

```
> house.names
[1] "name"      "  "        "     "     "         " "        " 
> Encoding(house.names)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

I tried to force the encoding to UTF-8 using `enc2utf8()` and `utf8_encode()` but these produce the same results, and strangely enough, after I try to force the encoding `Encoding()` still returns "unknown". Any way I do it, I end up with blank tick labels on my x-axis.

I searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Sys.setlocale()`.

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Japanese")
[1]"LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"

> house.names <- c("name", "平屋", "マンション", "湯河原 マンション", "熱海 マンション")
> house.names
[1] "name"              "平屋"              "マンション"       
[4] "湯河原 マンション" "熱海 マンション"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't change anything for me. :-(